# How to get Nginx with stream_ssl_module without recompiling (docker accepted)

Tags: ssl, nginx, module

I need to use the Nginx proxy configuration: proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate,
    proxy_ssl_verify, proxy_ssl_verify_depth

To get this, the installation guide says to recompile with --with-stream and with-stream_ssl_module (see: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-tcp-ssl-upstreams/).

But for production purposes it is not possible for me to compile.

Is there any way to get those options without compiling ? A dockerized Nginx container is an acceptable answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

I found that the Docker alpine of Nginx official repo is compiled with --with-stream and --with-stream_ssl_module. So it resolves my problem.
I cannot understand why Debian images doesn't contains thoses modules. This makes a break of compatibility between -alpine and not -alpine docker images.

Alpine images are available here : https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/